# replacing curley braces with new text

Tags: javascript, regex

```
il8n = {
  'en-us':{
    hello:"Hello Everyone",
    goodbye:"See ya later",
    welcome:"Hello how are you?",
    design:"Kandi Designs"
   }  
 };
 function translate(){
   var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; 
   var body = document.body || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
   var html = body.innerHTML;
   body.innerHTML = body.innerHTML.replace(/({T_(.*?)})/g, il8n[userLang.toLowerCase()][$1.replace(/{T_|},'').toLowerCase()]);
  }

 translate();
```

Basically what I want to do is get rid of `{T_Hello}` to `Hello Everyone` but since I suck at regex my capture groups and using `$1` I can't get this correctly.  Can anyone assist in this a wee bit?

Comment: FYI, `var body = document.body || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];` doesn't need the 2nd part as `document.body` is always good.  Also, you aren't use the `html` variable.

Comment: Haha yeah just realized that `html` part.

Comment: Also I always do that with body just as a precaution. It's an old habit that won't die

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea. $1, however, is not a variable where you use it. Change the second argument to `replace` to this:

```
function (match, $1) {
    return il8n[userLang.toLowerCase()][$1.toLowerCase()];
}
```

[`replace` can take a function as an argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). Then, shorten the capture group in the regex to this:

```
/{T_(.*?)}/g
```

This saves you some unnecessary string processing inside the replace function. On an unrelated note, regarding performance, you might want the server to send the appropriate `il8n` object based on the `Accept-Language` header, or, even better, do the insertions itself instead of relying on flaky and slow client-side code (making it cacheable).

Comment: perfecto! I always forget it can take a function :/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your il8n object keys you could do this to check for `T_` followed by any uppercase letters.

`/T_([A-Z]+)/`

You could add lowercase or numbers to it too:

`/T_([A-Za-z0-9]+)/`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
body.innerHTML = body.innerHTML.replace(
    /({T_(.*?)})/g, 
    function (s) { return il8n [userLang.toLowerCase()] [s.replace(/{T_|}/g,'').toLowerCase()]; } 
);
```

The second argument of `replace()` can be a string or a function that takes so many arguments as there are ()-groups in the regular expression, which in your case is one.

Indeed, if you write

```
s.replace (/a/g, 'b')
```

then, obviously, `replace()` receives two strings. However, if you write

```
s.replace (/a/g, f(x))
```

then again, `replace()` receives two strings, the second being the string returned from `f(x)`, so if `f(x)` returns `'b'`, then the two expressions above are equivalent. Since `f(x)` is executed before `replace()` has a chance to see it, it cannot use the special variables like `$1`, since at the point of call they are not defined.

If you want the code to be executed by `replace()`, then it should be executable code:

```
replace (/a/g, function (x) { return ' [' + x + '] found! '; } )
```

so that at the point of call, the function object is formed and this function is called inside `replace` with the argument $1 each time (note the global modifier g in the regex).

Note that your code will only work if placed below the text or called onload(), not above the text:

```
<body>
{T_hello} reader!
<script>
your code
</script>
<body>
```

works, but

```
<body>
<script>
your code
</script>
{T_hello} reader!
<body>
```

doesn't, because when it is executed, there is nothing still in `<body>`. The best place to call it is in `<body onload='translate()'>`.

I also corrected a typo in your code: `s.replace(/{T_|}` should be `s.replace(/{T_|}/`.

And another error in your code is: `s.replace(/{T_|}/` should be `s.replace(/{T_|}/g`, because it is supposed to make two replacements, not one.